# Azure Cloud Service + SQL Azure and firewall configuration

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've a single Web Role Cloud Service instance running the South East Asia, with a SQL Azure Database running in the same region. I am hitting a firewall issue and the connection is blocked unless I add the Cloud Services public virtual IP to the SQL server firewall.

From everything I've read, if the two systems are in the same region, and 'Allowed Windows Azure Services' is enabled (which adds 0.0.0.0 to the firewall), then the two should be able to communicate internally?

I have some concerns about things being routed inappropriately (is data going outside the network / am I being charged for it), and having to reconfigure the firewall should the VIP change.

Is there some other address I am supposed to access the SQL azure instance by (currently hitting blah.database.windows.net)?

Comment: if data is leaving the data centre then yes you are being charged for it - although this won't be happening if your db is definitely in the same region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. If I were you I would open a support ticket with Microsoft; I have heard of this issue before, although I never experienced it myself. This sounds like an issue, so report it and watch your next invoice carefully.

Comment: Opened a ticket and got a call from Azure, they confirmed an issue and their ops team are looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

Allowed Windows Azure Services - Will allow only azure services to access the database.

Secondly,

To be able to access the database server from any other endpoint, you need to add firewall rules to allow those specific IP ranges. If you want to connect from a machine with ip, 132.99.xx.xx you need to add a rule with start IP and end IP as 132.99.xx.xx

Hope this helps!